# C create a file path

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, filepath

I have this directory tree:

```
xy@xy:/test# find .
.
./2
./2/Asd
./2/Asd/qwe
./2/Asd/qwe/txt.txt
./1
```

There can be more directories like 4, 5, 6, whatever in the "test" folder, but asd, Asd, ASD, qwe, Qwe, QWE are constant.
The aim is to calculate all possible paths like this:

```
/test/1/ASD/QWE/txt.txt
/test/2/asd/qwe/txt.txt
/test/2/Asd/Qwe/txt.txt
```

and after that to read the file (txt.txt)

I created (copy & pasted together...) the following and it is working for a while.
I marked the line I have problem with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *filetosearch="txt.txt";
char *test="/test/";
char *slash="/";
char *directory[3][3] = {{"asd", "Asd", "ASD"}, {"qwe","Qwe","QWE"}};
int dircounter1=0;
int dircounter2=0;
FILE *filetosf;
char **dirpatharr=NULL;
int dirpathcount=0;
char **hdarr=NULL;
int hdarrcount=0;
char **fullpath=NULL;
int count,size;
char *dirname;
DIR  *d;
struct dirent *dir;
int main(void)
{
    d = opendir(test);
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            if( dir->d_type==DT_DIR )
            {
                dirname=dir->d_name;
                if((strcmp( dirname, ".." ) == 0) || (strcmp( dirname, "." ) == 0) )
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    hdarr=(char **)realloc(hdarr,(hdarrcount+1)*sizeof(dirname));
                    hdarr[hdarrcount]=dirname;
                    hdarrcount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(d);

    for (count=0; count<hdarrcount; count++ )
    {
        for (dircounter1 = 0; dircounter1 < 3; dircounter1++ )
        {
            for (dircounter2 = 0; dircounter2 < 3; dircounter2++ )
            {
                fullpath = malloc ( strlen(test) + strlen(hdarr[count]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(directory[0][dircounter2]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(directory[1][dircounter1]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(filetosearch)+1);
                strcpy (fullpath,test);
                strcat (fullpath,hdarr[count]);
                strcat (fullpath,slash);
                strcat (fullpath,directory[0][dircounter2]);
                strcat (fullpath,slash);
                strcat (fullpath,directory[1][dircounter1]);
                strcat (fullpath,slash);
                strcat (fullpath,filetosearch);

                printf("fullpath:%s\n",fullpath);
                //    filetosf = fopen(fullpath,"r");  //THIS WILL BE THE PROBLEM!!!!

                if (filetosf){
                    fseek (filetosf, 0L, SEEK_END);
                    size=ftell(filetosf);
                    fclose(fullpath);
                    printf("file exist:%s\n",fullpath);
                }
                free (fullpath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-------CUT HERE--------------------

It has this output (like I wanted):

```
fullpath:/test/2/asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/Asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/ASD/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/Asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/ASD/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/Asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/2/ASD/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/Asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/ASD/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/Asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/ASD/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/Asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test/1/ASD/QWE/txt.txt
```

BUT when I remove the remark sign and activate the file open part `filetosf = fopen(fullpath,"r");` 
I am not able to read the file. When I check the output I get this:

```
fullpath:/test/2/asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//Asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//Asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//Asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//Asd/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//asd/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/Qwe/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//Asd/QWE/txt.txt
fullpath:/test//ASD/QWE/txt.txt
```

This even happens if I print out the lines BEFORE the `fopen` commend. Why is this happening?

I am not an experienced programer, so please try to explain simply.

Comment: The '<TAB>' key is usually located in the upper left part of the keyboard, have you noticed yet that it is there?

Comment: I was going to write exactly the same. I don't know if I want to take time to indent his code or go do my dishes.

Comment: Yep :) it was formatted in source but when I pasted all went away. this is my first post here , I was lame.

Comment: whoever formatted for me> thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the *many* things that are odd in this code, the blatant outright error immediately apparent is:

```
fullpath = malloc ( strlen(test) + strlen(hdarr[count]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(directory[0][dircounter2]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(directory[1][dircounter1]) + strlen(slash) + strlen(filetosearch)+1);
```

followed by a raft of  string copies like:

```
strcpy (fullpath,test);
```

Note: `fullpath` is declared as such:

```
char **fullpath = NULL;
```

Which declares a pointer-to-char-pointer; **not** a pointer-to-char.Try turning on warnings, then re-examine everyplace you  use this variable after declaring it correctly:

```
char *fullpath = NULL;
```

---

Next, you *save* (and I use that term loosely) the directory names you're building up as such:

```
dirname=dir->d_name;
...
hdarr[hdarrcount]=dirname;
```

But ll this does is save the d_name address into a new slot in your hdarr dynamic array. The address is not valid as soon as you invoke readdir() again (or closedir()). From the `readdir()` documentation:

"**The data returned by readdir() may be overwritten by subsequent calls to readdir() for the same directory stream.**"

Therefore all those pointers you're storing are in implementation-owned memory that it is completely free to blast-over whenever/however it sees fit. You need to make copies of these if you want to keep them (and of course free() those copies when you're finished).

HowTo fix this:

I don't normally recommend this, but in your case I will: use strdup() on the dirname.  This is a poor-mans "alloc me a string buffer the size of that one, including space for a null-term, copy the string over,and return the pointer to me. So your code will look like this:

```
else
{
    char **pp = realloc(hdarr,(hdarrcount+1)*sizeof(*pp));
    if (pp)
    {
        hdaerr = pp;
        hdarr[hdarrcount++] = strdup(dir->d_name);
    }
    else
    {   // panic ensues
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Do NOT forget to free this correctly. Each string pointer in your hdarr is dynamically allocated. Make sure you free them, then the array itself. The tail of your code (right before exit) should look something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<hdarrcount;i++)
    free(hdarr[i]);
free(hdarr);
```

---

Minor, but important:

**Never** do this:

```
hdarr=(char **)realloc(hdarr,(hdarrcount+1)*sizeof(dirname));
```

If `realloc()` fails it returns NULL and you just lost (and thereby leaked) you're original data pointer. Do this instead:

```
char **pp = realloc(hdarr,(hdarrcount+1)*sizeof(*pp));
if (pp)
{
    hdaerr = pp;
    // .. continue with the rest of your assignment code
}
else
{   // allocation error, but at least you still have the 
    // old hdaerr so you can free it.
}
```

---

Next, as someone else pointed out:

```
fclose(fullpath);
```

This is entirely wrong. `fclose()` expects a `FILE *`, not a char **. Pass it the filetosf you opened earlier (and by opened, I mean after uncommenting the problem line you've currently taken out. once you do that then:

```
fclose(filetosf);
```

Note: Until you do that comment out **all** of the fopen through fclose() code lines. as them hitting a NULL file pointer is once-again-say-it-with-us... **undefined**.

Comment: there must be something. there are many warnings... I will try to check them.

Comment: i changed
char **fullpath = NULL;
to
char *fullpath = NULL;
ALL Warnings gone. but the output remain the same like
/test//Asd/qwe/txt.txt

Comment: Thank You for your help, Problem solved with your "HowTo fix this:" part.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
fclose(fullpath);
```

Comment: This is not helpful. You should explain why it is wrong and how OP can solve this. Or if you feel it's too obvious (which it may be), vote for closure instead of providing half an answer.

Comment: It's obvious once you spot the wrong line. If you look into the manual page of fclose.

Comment: Enabling and reading compiler warnings could help, too. There should be a warning about a type mismatch between char** and FILE*.

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:249: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
./go.c:75: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fclose’ from incompatible pointer type


Yes it is there, but how can I pass the finalpath to fopen in a correct way?

Comment: Do not pass the path to fclose at all. Because, when you read the manual, you'll see that it expects a FILE*. As the compiler tells you. So you pass the FILE* you got from fopen.

Comment: Also, in the definition of fullpath, there are too many stars. I think. So you probably got even more compiler warnings. Try to understand and fix them. If you can't understand them (after searching the web), ask again.

Comment: You are right. It was a mistake conserning fclose but it did not solve the problem

Comment: All compiler warnings gone? Even with -Wall? And problem still not solved? Then post the updated code.